# Influxdb + grafana : daily count on timeseries

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have a timeseries with a value column. 
I want to get a cumulative count of values per days.

For example if I have for day 1 following points :

(timestamp1, value1) (timestamp2, value2) (timestamp3, value3)

I want to have a graph with :

- zero value displayed for day 1 00:00 to timestamp1
- 1 value displayed for timestamp1 to timestamp2
- 2 value displayed for timestamp2 to timestamp3
- 3 value displayed for timestamp3 to day2 00:00
- zero value displayed for day 2 00:00 to first value of day2
  and so on

I could do such a request :

```
select count(value) from series where time = today group by time($interval)
```

But I won't get expected result as "group by" doesn't do a cumulative count a values per day but a cumulative count of value per $interval. 
And if I do   :

```
select count(value) from series where time = today group by time(today)
```

I will only have 1 count value per day.

How can I do it?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this?  I am trying to achieve a similar thing but with no success so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, but could this be a solution?

select count(value) from series where time = today group by time(24h)